# How can I create "suffixed-by-number" variables in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, sas

Is there a way to create "suffixed-by-number" variables/columns in a Python data frame?

I am trying to replicate some of SAS' "first.", "last.", and "retain" capabilities in Python, but have not been successful.  This is what my data set looks like:

```
Name     Grade
Lee      A
Lee      A+
Lee      A+
Lee      A+
Col      B+
Col      A
Col      B+
```

I would like to summarize the above information so that I only output one record per Name.  This is the desired output:

```
Name    _Grade01    _Grade02    _Grade03    _Grade04
Lee     A            A+         A+          A+
Col     B+           A          B+
```

In SAS, the code would be:

```
array _Grade{*} _Grade01-_Grade04;
if first.Name then do;
    n = 0;
    do _i = 1 to 4;
        _Grade[_i] = 0;
    end;
end;

n + 1;

if n>0 and n <=4 then do;
    _Grade[n] = Grade;
end;

if last.Name then do;
    output;
end;
```

Is there a way to efficiently replicate this in Python?

Thank you.

Comment: Python supports lists. You don't need `Grade1` to be defined as its own name when you can use `Grade[1]` (which is a syntax whereby `Grade` is the name of a list, and `1` is the index used to access a position in that list). The syntax for dicts is very similar.

Comment: Don't do this. Do not dynamically create variables, use a *container*, like a list or a dict

Comment: I'm not sure why they didn't just use `proc transpose`. I'm sure you can recreate this with `pivot` or `pivot_table`.